# How to turn returned Dictionaries into one large list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have this little bit of code which queries jobs we have on the database with certain attributes. I then want to isolate the job IDs alone, which I've done, but it returns the results in a bunch of different dictionaries.

How can I merge all the dictionaries together then convert it into 1 large list with only the job IDs? I am using Python 2.7.

```
import pprint


with aftractor.utils.tractor_connection() as tq:
    ma_jobs = tq.jobs('not done and maxactive', columns=['jid', 'title'])
    ma_search = tq.jobs('not done and maxactive', columns=['jid'])
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(ma_jobs)

print ma_search
```

Return value:

> [{u'jid': 3207827}, {u'jid': 3221652}, {u'jid': 3221482}, {u'jid': 3221109}, {u'jid': 3229185}, {u'jid': 3228951}, {u'jid': 3228953}, {u'jid': 3228952}, {u'jid': 3228960}, {u'jid': 3228956}, {u'jid': 3228950}, {u'jid': 3228022}, {u'jid': 3227226}, {u'jid': 3227982}, {u'jid': 3227985}, {u'jid': 3227984}, {u'jid': 3227980}, {u'jid': 3229049}, {u'jid': 3228337}]

What I want:

> [3207827, 3221652, 3221482, 3221109, 3229185, 3228951, 3228953, 3228952, 3228960, 3228956, 3228950, 3228022, 3227226, 3227982, 3227985, 3227984, 3227980, 3229049, 3228337]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following comprehension:

```
>>> [d[u'jid'] for d in ma_jobs]
[3207827,
 3221652,
 3221482,
 3221109,
 3229185,
 3228951,
 3228953,
 3228952,
 3228960,
 3228956,
 3228950,
 3228022,
 3227226,
 3227982,
 3227985,
 3227984,
 3227980,
 3229049,
 3228337]
```

Basically, you are using a list comprehension. Every element in `ma_jobs` is a dictionary that has one element which key is `u'jid'`, so you are basically taking the value associated with that key, and adding it to the list that is created on the fly.

Comment: Not sure I follow, would it be possible for you to elaborate a bit on how I would implement this piece of code within my existing structure?

Comment: @AMist, I just added a more detailed explanation, and this code works in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `map` function, right after  `ma_jobs = tq.jobs('not done and maxactive', columns=['jid', 'title'])`:

```
result = list(map(lambda elem: elem['jid'], ma_jobs))
```

Result:

```
[3207827, 3221652, 3221482, 3221109, 3229185, 3228951, 3228953, 3228952, 3228960, 3228956, 3228950, 3228022, 3227226, 3227982, 3227985, 3227984, 3227980, 3229049, 3228337]
```

Comment: Couple issues, this gets rid of my ma_jobs query, which is seperate from the ma_search query. I need both. I tried applying it to ma_search in the same format, but it says map() requires atleast two arguments.

also, it returns the list in a vertical format like shown above my imiguelvargasf


I need a horizontal format as you showed above.

Comment: The list of dictionaries that you posted as a result, is `ma_jobs` or `ma_search`? As for the format, what do you mean by saying _horizontal_? The output I am getting is horizontal.

Comment: I'm getting it with a JID on each line like Imiguelvargasf has in his comment. The dictionary result is ma_search

Comment: @A Mist if could post some sample data from `ma_search`, you would help me resolve this issue.